# Unstable system when controlling power to serial peripheral devices and sleeping

Tags: serial, power, i2c, interrupt, sleep

In the process of trying to make a small system that will last a while on 4 AA batteries, I've reduced my Arduino project to a barebones system that when asleep draws a tiny amount of current from the batteries.

However, to achieve this, I found it would be necessary to cut power to the two attached peripheral devices (connected to an ATMega328P-PU). One of them is an I2C device, and the other is a serial device, and both are attached to the hardware serial/I2C pins as appropriate.

In terms of powering the peripherals, the bases of two transistors are connected to two of the digital pins, and power to them is controlled from code via these transistors. Both devices are 5V, and when the system is running the total current draw is around 200mA.

Basically this setup works, however I'm getting "random" system hanging and essentially an unreliable project. Sometimes when I power it up it will work as normal, but then hang and not sleep. Other times, it will sleep, but then freeze after waking or just get stuck during waking (which I can tell because the serial device powers up first and does nothing, but the I2C device remains off).

My best guess is the root of the cause is either something to do with the serial communication being interrupted by sleeping the MPU (I'm using the maximum power saving sleep, which is woken by an external interrupt on pin 2), or possibly some sort of power problem (sudden current draw from battery?) that occurs when the peripherals are powered on in code (though I don't know how I should test this).

So far, I've tried calling `Serial.end()` before sleeping the MPU, and `Serial.being(9600)` on waking, and have scattered `delay(1000)`s throughout to ensure everything has enough time to get running, but the problem still remains.

Does anyone have any pointers on things I could change/test, or an alternative approach I could take to make the same power savings?

EDIT: Some more details

The transitors used are TIP 120's. The connections are essentially an exact copy of the image here: https://ctheds.files.wordpress.com/2007/10/tip120.jpg, except the resistors used are 560 Ohms (just what I had to hand, no other reason, didn't think it would change anything).

The I2C peripheral is a 20x4 LCD (which I believe is HD44780 compliant). The serial device is an GT511C3 fingerprint sensor. I don't believe either of them have any automatic power saving features, though I haven't looked for such things in the documentation explicitly.

The exact code I use to call sleep is

```
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
sleep_enable();
sleep_mode();
```

which I'm lead to believe is the lowest power mode, and aside from this problem works well for my system.

Comment: Please show us how you connected the peripherals with the transistors? Which transistors did you use? What peripherals do you use, as some have power saving features themselves? Also, please post the code where it hangs. Power spikes/dips seems like a possible explanation. You could use the watchdog timer to reset the arduino when it hangs, but that isn't really a fix for original problem.

Comment: What sleep mode do you use? In some recent experiments, I found out that ATmega USART (serial comm) was not compatible with ANY sleep mode except the IDLE mode.

Comment: Also you might consider replacing your transistors with MOSFETs, which shall reduce consumption further.

Comment: Does it work as intended if you remove the transistors, but use the sleep mode? I mean, maybe the sleepmode is the problem itself

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I have updated the question with more details.
@Gerben I had considered the watchdog timer, but as you say it wouldn't help me as I would lose the state my program was in before it was reset.

Comment: @jfpoilpret I'm interested to hear more about your experiments. Do you mean serial will simply not work after sleep? Just to be clear, I am not using a serial interrupt to wake the MPU.

Comment: @AllanNørgaard The previous iteration of my project did exactly this. The MPU was put to sleep, but the peripherals were always on. The battery just didn't last long enough to be viable.

Comment: Make sure all output pins going to the peripherals are set to high, or you might damage them. Try adding a large capacitor to the power rail, and see if that helps. You probably want to disable the brownout detection during sleep (`sleep_bod_disable()`). (I haven't had problems with powerdown and serial communications.)

Comment: @Gerben Thanks for the suggestions. I already have a 10uF capacitor on the rails. I don't think I need to go bigger? It seems the chip I'm using doesn't have BOD sleep, since when I try to compile with it I'm told it's not defined. I've done a few more experiments and I'm "quite" sure that the serial device is causing the problem. I'm not sure if it helps to mention, but the library can be found here: http://goo.gl/jOemCc. By default the library uses SoftwareSerial, which I thought was the problem, so I modified it to use HW serial. Have you needed to call `Serial.end()` to sleep in the past?

Comment: I didn't call `Serial.end()`, but I only used it to send data to my PC, never to receive. The `sleep_bod_disable()` Macro isn't available in the Arduino IDE for some reason, but you can probably find the actual code somewhere ([or use this one](https://github.com/reeedstudio/libraries/blob/master/sleep_bod_disable/sleep_bod_disable.h)). I'd try a bigger cap, if you have one, as it's very little effort, and might just fix it. Where did you put the transistors? On the 5v or on the GND going to the fingerprint reader.

Comment: @Gerben Thanks, I'll give the bigger capacitor a try. I'm using the transistor to switch the sensors ground wire, the 5V is connected to the 5V rail. I assume you were using hardware serial in your project as opposed to a software serial port?

Comment: If you switch the GND, you have to make sure all the pins going into the module are also 5V or (high impedance) inputs. Or current could flow from the 5V rail, through the module, to the GND on the signal wire, possibly damaging the module, and even the arduino. I'm not saying that's the case here, as it depends on how the module/IC is build. Most datasheet tell that the input voltage should be more that a few tenths of a volt below ground. If ground is disconnected/floating, a low input signal will be like -5V. PS yes, I used hardware serial.

Comment: Be aware that running the AVR straight from the battery works, but might require to speed down the clock (16MHz requires a minimum of 3.7v according to the spec) I had a couple of similar problems in my project and 'solved' them with a rather brutal approach (https://holadimake.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/building-a-cellular-tracker-part3a-circumventing-unreliable-watchdog-with-external-555-timer/).

Comment: I see, do you mean use a 555 timer to act as a slower, external clock? My power source is 4.8V, so I would have thought that would be good enough to mean that an external clock is not necessary?

Comment: I'd suspect the clock rate too. Plus make sure you don't run out of memory. Most common causes for freezing code is low memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using an NPN transistor to control power to a peripheral may be problematic.

An NPN transitor would presumably be used as a `low-side switch` interrupting the peripheral's ground line, however, even when turned on this will have a non-trivial voltage drop.

Most logic level definitions are asymmetric, ie, the maximimum legal voltage for a logic "0" is relatively low. If you insert the voltage drop of a bipolar transistor into a peripheral's ground line, then it may be borderline unable to drive a fully legal '0' to the ATmega, which is reference to the lower true ground and would see the peripheral's ground difference added to its output voltage.

A better approach would be to use either a high-side switch (as there is typically more room between the minimum legal '1' and the supply) or else to use an FET switch which would have a much lower voltage drop.

Also keep in mind that most IC's are not specified to tolerate lasting I/O voltages much outside of the range of their power suppliers, and in fact their protection diodes may mean that application of such voltages effectively powers them through the I/O pin.  So before turning off power to a peripheral, you probably want the ATmega software to assert all shared I/O lines towards the side of the peripheral supply which is not being disconnected, ie, for a low side switch drive everything high and for a high side switch drive everything low.

Finally, the process of power cycling could potentially confuse peripheral interface engines and it is possible that some error flags set in this process might never be cleared.  So you may want to clear the flags of and generally re-initialize your USART, I2C, etc on resume.

Comment: Sadly, this is a long dead project, and the bits to put it back together are a bit scattered... Nevertheless, I am most interested by your take on things. These are problems I hadn't considered (or even realised existed, coming from a largely software background). Thanks very much! I hope that if I get around to trying something like this again in the future it will succeed!

Answer (score 0):

I hear great things about the cosa core for Arduino. It's a fantastic alternative Arduino core and exposes the power management capabilities of the micro-controller that are not exposed by the standard Arduino core.

You might find it is too different for your experience but then again it is excellent and worth a look.

https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa